# How to transform a line during pan gesture event?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

I am creating a flow chart and when user drags a node, I want to move the line connected to it. In pan handler event of the node I implemented a `CGAffineTransform` to transform line, but it does not move line smoothly. Any idea how other flow chart apps handle this problem?

```
func panHandler(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        else if (sender.state == .Changed)
        {
            let translation = sender.translationInView(self)
            sender.view!.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y + translation.y)


           //rv is the connected line, created at an other place like:
           //let w = GraphViewController.calcLength(e.x, y0: e.y, x1: e2.x, y1: e2.y)
           //rv = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(w), 1.0))
           //var angle = GraphViewController.calcAngle(e.x, y0: e.y, x1: e2.x, y1: e2.y)
           //rv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(angle))

            var angle = GraphViewController.calcAngle(e!.x, y0: e!.y, x1: r.destination!.x, y1:r.destination!.y)
            rv!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(angle))

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to put rv!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(angle)) into a animation block?

Comment: Do you sure, that angle is measured in radians, but not degrees? CGAffineTransformMakeRotation required angle in radians. I don't remember how it will looks in Swift, but in Objective C it will be like:
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 animations:^{
  rv.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * angle);
 }];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't need any touch events on the line, we could use a plain `CAShapeLayer` and update its path on pan. I assume you want to have some anchor point for the line.

Define some anchor point for your line

```
endOfLineAnchor = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2, y: view.bounds.height * 0.8)
```

Create some view to attach it to

```
ballView = createBallView()
ballView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2, y: view.bounds.height / 2)
```

Add layer & view

```
    lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    lineLayer.path = pathFromBallToAnchor()
    view.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
    view.addSubview(ballView)
```

On pan update the layer's path

```
    else if (sender.state == .Changed)
    {
        let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)
        sender.view!.center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y + translation.y)
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions)
        lineLayer.path = pathFromBallToAnchor()
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
```

the reason for the `CATransaction` is that we want to disable implicit animations.

Construct the path:

```
    func pathFromBallToAnchor() -> CGPathRef {
        var bazier = UIBezierPath()
        bazier.moveToPoint(ballView.center)
        bazier.addLineToPoint(endOfLineAnchor)
        return bazier.CGPath
    }
```

the result:

[image: Panned Ball attached to an anchored line in iPhone 5 iOS 8.1 simulator]